# PrimeFaces dialog not working in Chrome browser

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

As you can see I am trying to display a dialog box on click on the command link, the dialog is displayed in IE and Firefox, but not in Google Chrome v23, please suggest.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:tabView id="tabView">
        <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                <h:dataTable value="#{testBean.dataList}" var="data">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{data}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <p:commandLink action="#{testBean.loadCommentHistory(data)}"
                                       update=":myForm:tabView:dialog" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
                            <h:graphicImage url="resources/theme1/images/comments.gif"
                                            styleClass="basicImageStyle" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
                <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dynamic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg">
                    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.commentHistory}" />
                </p:dialog>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the dialog the dialog is reset to the default state which is hidden. If you call `dialog.show()` and update the dialog the dialog is hidden again. Chrome (being probably faster than IE or FireFox) seems to handle this differently. A solution would be to wrap the content of the dialog in a container and update the container.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{testBean.loadCommentHistory(data)}"
    update=":myForm:tabView:dialog-content" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
    <h:graphicImage url="resources/theme1/images/comments.gif"
        styleClass="basicImageStyle" />
</p:commandLink>

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dynamic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg">
    <p:outputPanel id="dialog-content">
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.commentHistory}" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsulate the page in a f:view tag if you haven't already. There is some problem when it is not present with Chrome and Safari. See http://primefaces.org/faq.html question 3

```
<html xmnls=... >
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            ....
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            ....
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```