# Command Link under tab using Ajax Primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I know that this question may be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776786/prime-faces-command-link-ajax-not-working) but I didn't understand the answer at all.

I am using a full page layout, in the left layout I have some nested accordion panels, tabs and command links. I want this links to update center layout content form.

**Left Layout:**

```
<h:form>
    <p:accordionPanel>
        <p:tab title="Parent Tab">
             <p:accordionPanel>
                 <p:tab title="Child Tab">
                     <p:commandLink value="link" update=":contentform" />
                 </p:tab>
             </p:accordionPanel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>             
</h:form>
```

**Center Layout:**

```
<h:form id="contentform">
    <ui:include src="#{layoutUI.viewId}" />
</h:form>
```

And a simple explanation will help cause the similar question lacks in that :(

Comment: The `<h:commandLink>` doesn't support the `update` attribute at all. Is this a careless typo while formulating the question or the real code?

Comment: @BalusC Yes I am sorry it is a typo. I meant `<p:commandLink>` and my problem is simple I just can't find a good article on ajax content updating.

Comment: Edit your question then. Well now I don't see any problem. Provided that this code is placed in a completely blank template (i.e. directly in `<h:body>` without any other tags), it should work fine. What exactly is your problem/question? Does it actually not work? Or does it work and do you not understand why you need to prefix the client ID with `:`?

Comment: @BalusC I edited my question, restarted the IDE and killed all the java processes in my PC, ran the application again and everything is fine now and I don't know what happened?
What I need as an answer is a details to understand the attribute update value.
And thank you for your effort this is the second time to help me :D

Comment: That part is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper use of the built in Ajax functionality of the `p:commandLink` component is to specify that the link will invoke an Ajax call with the `ajax` attribute.

```
<p:commandLink value="link" ajax="true" update=":contentform" />
```

Using the `:` in front will signify that you are looking for the ID of a component on the ViewRoot rather than its direct Naming Container so this is correct.  The only thing missing is the `ajax` attribute.